# Why does "save" overwrite "capture point" function?

Tags: qgis

I am very new at using QGIS. I have the standard installation (no additional plug-ins). I have several polygons and each polygon is formed by a number of segments. What I am trying to do is to connect the polygons with each other with new lines that I create. So for example I have two polygons (left and right are the two polygons) and I want to create a new segment from one point of the first polygon to another point on the second polygon.

[image]

[image]

I am using the "catch" function so it catches the points automatically. I create the segment (zoom in BEFORE saving, everything ok) BUT when I click  on "save changes" (for the segments layer) both ends of the new segment jump from their position (zoom in AFTER saving, not ok) and are not staying on the polygon-points they were captured on.

Why?

Also the identification chart of the new segment is empty and doesn't adopt the start and endnode. http://postimage.org/gallery/5fh42dqk/

[image]

[image]

I than tried to create a segment and type in manually the StartNode and EndNode but QGIS doesn't connect the two nodes at all.

How does this work?

Do I need a plugin for this?

---

I narrowed it down to a round up. When i save the changes i made to the layer (so NOT the project save) QGIS rounds up the coordinates to an accuracy of six decimals.

Why is that and how can i disable it?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new element, right-click (instead of left-click) on the last node you want to add. Then a textbox lets you add values for the attribute table. These values will not be automatically added to your attribute table!

The Save Button writes the data to the file. That's a different thing than adding objects.

For the snap function, you have to define the snapping radius in `Settings -> Options`, Digitizing tab, and what layers shall be used for snapping in `Settings-> Snap Options`.

For the first, I use 10 Pixel to see the cursor snap. If set to Map Units it may not snap at all.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be dealing with a routable network (judging from your layer names "RoutingSegments"). Please note that you were writing about "polygons" in your question which is rather confusing because the screenshots don't show any polygon layers. I therefore assume you want to add new edges (= new lines) to the RoutingSegments line layer.

Next, there seems to be a misunderstanding about what a GIS like QGIS does when new features are added. Values added in the attribute input dialog (which appears after right clicking) do not affect the geometries at all. (QGIS does not extend segments or anything similar.) Your only way to ensure connectivity is to use the snapping tools correctly.